# not showing HTML File when I try to run a .aspx file on Sharepoint

Tags: html, asp.net, sharepoint, office365, aspx-user-control

When I'm trying to run a .aspx file on Sharepoint, the file is not running rather the .aspx file is getting downloaded and the the static HTML page is opening with no CSS and JS running. What can I do.

I tried to rename the HTML file as .aspx file but there is nothing happening. The HTML file is opening but there is no CSS and JS in that, and when I run that file on some other browser it is running just fine.

Comment: You can't just save or toss in some .aspx page into a SharePoint site. However, you can add a "application" (aspx) page to the site as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/walkthrough-creating-a-sharepoint-application-page?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp